# .NET Core 3.1 app to use environment variables running in Kubernetes and fallback to appsettings.json when environment variable not set

Tags: c#, kubernetes, .net-core, environment-variables

I am trying to get my .NET Core 3.1 app to use environment variables when running in Kubernetes and fallback to `appsettings.json` when environment variable not set there.

I am using this in my `ConfigureServices` method in the startup file

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                                    .Build();
var dbname = configuration.GetSection("DB_NAME").Value;
```

My `appsettings.json` file has this

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "Data": {
            "DB_NAME":"test_db"
        }
    }
}
```

I am setting the environment variable using the following command on the command prompt.

```
setx DB_NAME ="Kube_test_db"
```

When I run the app in Visual Studio, I get the db name as `Kube_test_db`. When I delete the User environment variable on Windows 10 system settings and run the app again in Visual Studio, this line returns null.

```
var dbname = configuration.GetSection("DB_NAME").Value;
```

What am I missing to get the value to fall back to what is defined in the `appsettings.json` file?

Comment: Does it run before deleting user environment variable? Is there any reason to delete it?

Comment: I want to fall back to appsettings in case the environment variables have not been setup for whatever reason

Answer (score 0):

[Use `.AddJsonFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.jsonconfigurationextensions.addjsonfile?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_JsonConfigurationExtensions_AddJsonFile_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfigurationBuilder_System_String_).

And do it before you call `.AddEnvironmentVariables()`. Like so:

```cs
        new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
```

Comment: I dont get hostingEnvironment in the configure method where I need it. Also, I will need to change the `var dbname = configuration.GetSection("DB_NAME").Value;` to `var dbname = configuration.GetSection("Appsettings:Data:DB_NAME").Value;` to get the value from the appsettings.json. This doesn't match the environment variable which is only `DB_NAME`. If I put the environment variable as `Appsettings:Data:DB_NAME` and run the code as `dbname = configuration.GetSection("Appsettings:Data:DB_NAME").Value;` then I still get the value from the appsettings.json and not from the environment.

Comment: Use `__` (2 underscores) as the separator for *setting* the environment variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration&view=aspnetcore-6.0#naming-of-environment-variables